# defining code on vba excel to simplify code writing process

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to reduce the amount of clutter on my code by creating "shortcuts" if you will

For instance, I always have to type

```
ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range
```

Is there a way for me to define the above to create a less wordy macro? I have tried convert to range and string and the former returns an error (but I could still get intellisense recognize and attempt to autofill) while the string version doesnt work.

Comment: 'Wordy' code equals faster execution time and fewer errors. You just have to write good code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create functions or customized properties, which are always evaluated when called

```
Property Get pARng As Range
    Set pARng = ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range
End Property

Function fARng As Range
    Set fARng = ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range
End Function

'Usage
Sub xxx

    '...

    pARng.Rows(1).Activate
    'Same as ThisWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range.Rows(1).Activate

    fARng.Rows(1).Activate
    'using function instead achieves same result
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like in any programming language, you can **use variables to store data**
For example:

`Dim myrange As Range: Set myrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")`

Alternatively, if you will be working with the **same object multiple times**, you can **use the `With` keyword**
For example. instead of writing you want to work with table every time on every new line you can do

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   .ListRows.Add
   .ListColumns(2).Range(3) = "Hello World!"
   ' ... and so on
End With
```

---

Also, please on a sidenote: Avoid using `Select/ActiveSheet/ActiveWorkbook` and so on!
More info on how to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)